# Are complex exponentials real thing?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier-series, laplace-transform

Is there any physical significance of complex exponentials.

I mean can we produce them like how we can produce sinusoidal signals using a signal generator?

OR are they just pure mathematical convenience that help us in signal analysis?

I am expecting more of an intuitive answer rather than an abstract mathematical relationships.

Comment: Both real and imaginary :D

Comment: Ok, now taking you seriously, they are a mathematical abstraction, but depending on what you are modeling, the imaginary part will may have fundamental physical meaning. For instance, in electrical impedance the imaginary part determines how the current is affected by changes in the voltage.

Comment: I am of the persuasion that actual physical quantities, that have effect that we can measure (or feel or whatever) are real and that imaginary quantities are really useful mathematical abstraction that saves us a lotta work and can also lead to insights (like how to manipulate complex I/Q signals).  But when you put a meter or scope onto a voltage, that's a real value that you're measuring.  Imaginary quantities are something that we, and the computers we program, imagine..  All equations involving complex quantities can be changed into a pair of equations involving only real quantities.

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos(\omega t)$ exists then so does too $e^{j\omega t}$, both exist equally as mathematical abstractions used to describe our physical world. Even though we use the unfortunate naming of “real” and “imaginary”, neither is more real than the other.

If creating a sinusoid with a signal generator makes it a "real thing" (not meaning the mathematical term "real"), then yes we can also create complex exponentials with a signal generator.   We may feel that sinusoids are more of a real thing since we can measure real waveforms such as sinusoids with one scope probe. To measure complex waveforms we would use two scope probes measured at two test points.

We create complex numbers as ordered pairs or real numbers: such as $I+jQ$ where $I$ is a real number representing the real component, and $Q$ is a real number representing the imaginary component: or magnitude and phase as $Ae^j\phi$ where $A$ is a real number representing the magnitude and $\phi$ is a real number representing the phase. Waveforms are continuous or discrete streams of such numbers, so for us to produce a complex waveform we would require two streams of real waveforms. We do this whether it is on paper in an analysis or creating signals in a lab. Thus, a complex number or waveform can only “exist” for observation when two measurement points are available.

Below is an example signal generator that creates complex waveforms directly. This Vector Signal Generator takes in complex waveforms as $I+jQ$ (see the "I" and "Q" on the front right panel for the A and B inputs) as well as provides complex waveforms out as $I$ and $Q$ from the back panel:

[image: Signal Generator]

This generator provides the single complex frequencies as a waveform consisting of pairs of sinusoids, but we could easily create the waveform as a magnitude vs time paired with a phase versus time. In either case we require two separate data paths each that can be represented individually using streams of real numbers, but combined can be represented as a single stream of complex numbers. Both are equally mathematical abstractions in that regard when we refer to "real", "imaginary" and "complex".

Another example of using a complex waveform is an IQ downconverter where a real waveform at a high frequency carrier frequency called the RF frequency is frequency translated to baseband (DC) as a complex $I+jQ$ waveform out:

[image: IQ Downconverter]

The inputs and data-paths above are all differential except for the final output. So each differential pair represents one real waveform. The RF (high frequency) input is a real input. The VCO is a voltage controlled oscillator creating a single real frequency tone (often referred to as LO as local oscillator), which is then split into quadrature to create what we could refer to as a single complex frequency tone. The two multipliers for a single real to complex multiplier with a real input, complex LO and complex output. The complex output is then low pass filtered (LPF) and sampled with Analog to Digital Converters (ADC).

The block diagram below is the same as the one above, where I represent the separate $I$ and $Q$ paths above as one single complex waveform with wider arrows along with the spectrums showing how the IQ downconverter translates the real spectrum to a complex spectrum. All real spectrums are complex conjugate symmetric, so in order to have the spectrum at baseband as shown, it must be complex as this physical frequency translator will do. I believe the simplicity in this block diagram (which is identical to the one above) shows the intuition and simplicity that working with complex waveforms can provide. [Complex, but not complicated](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/essay/quadrature_signals.pdf)!

[image: IQ spectrums]

To see the motivation for using complex exponentials vs sinusoids note that the two are related by:

$$Ae^{j\phi} = \frac{A}{2}\cos(\phi) + j \frac{A}{2}\sin(\phi)$$

Where we see the polar form as magnitude and phase on the left related to the rectangular form as real and imaginary components on the right. Even if the implementations are done using the rectangular form, certain operations are more readily analyzed in polar form such as if we wanted to correct for a small frequency offset at the baseband output. For instance if we wished to shift the lowest spectrum labeled "D" in the plot above down slightly by $\omega_\Delta$:

The complex waveform at the $D$ output can be represented in polar form as:

$$x(t) = A(t)e^{j(\omega t+\phi(t))}$$

To frequency translate, we simply multiply by a single frequency tone which is a complex exponential as $y(t)=e^{-j\omega_\Delta t}$. When we multiply, exponents sum, so the shift is intuitive:

$$x(t)y(t) = A(t)e^{j(\omega t+\phi(t))}e^{-j\omega_\Delta t} = A(t)e^{j((\omega-\omega_\Delta)t+\phi(t))}$$

If we did this same operation with sines and cosines it would be:

$$x(t) = \frac{A}{2}\cos(\omega(t)+\phi(t))+j\frac{A}{2}\sin(\omega(t)+\phi(t))$$

$$y(t) = \cos(\omega_\Delta t) - j\sin(\omega_\Delta t)$$

I will leave it to the reader to multiply out $x(t)y(t)$ using the rectangular representations above. This shows how often an analysis often proceeds more easily and readily in polar form while the final implementation once determined is often done in rectangular form for the convenience of both cases but either on paper or on the circuit board we can represent the waveforms of interest in either polar or rectangular form.

Comment: see comment above.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I agree with that perspective-- If we limit ourselves to physical units, they are all real and singular (I suspect, is there a counter case?). However like complex numbers there are other "real" things described with more than just one real number: For example, 3D position require 3 real numbers, that doesn't mean our position doesn't exist. So I think the commonality here is the numbers themselves are equally abstractions in all cases (and in all cases complex, quarternion, etc real numbers are used- that's all we have, we just start ordering them for additional meaning